# Reference(Source) directly under the caption

Tags: biblatex, captions, biber

Is there a way to write the refernce of a figure directly under the Figure?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my.bib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs}   

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
    @article{somebody-sgt,
      ids       =   {someone-sgt},
      author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
      title     =   {Some Great Title},
      journal   =   {Best Journal},
      year      =   3019,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      volume    =   3,
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics{whatever}
\caption[Test Test,]   {%
  \tabular[t]{@{}l@{}}Test Test, 1. Zeile\\%
  Test Test 2. Zeile \\%
  \hspace{-2.2cm} Quelle:~\cite[S. 23]{somebody-sgt} \endtabular \label{fig:MIMOKanal}}
\end{figure}





\end{document}
```

Comment: `\\Source: some source` after `\includegraphics{whatever}`? I'm not quite understanding the question...

Comment: I'd like to add the reference/source of a figure directly under the caption, as shown in the figure. One way to achieve this was by giving the line with the reference/source of the figure an offset (\hspace{-2.2cm}), but this seems to be quite inelegant. My I'm is to find a more general way to achieve this without adding to every pic an offset.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, readers are familiar with the concept of citations. My suggestion is to simply add it to your description (caption) just like it would be regular text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}   

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{somebody-sgt,
      ids       =   {someone-sgt},
      author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
      title     =   {Some Great Title},
      journal   =   {Best Journal},
      year      =   3019,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      volume    =   3,
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{4cm}
\caption[Test Test,]{This is some caption. It describes the
    graphic, which obviously is by someone else. To make that clear
    for everybody, we cite the entry. The reader will be
    experienced enough, to know what to do with those letters and
    numbers in
    parenthesis.~\autocite[S.~23]{somebody-sgt}\label{fig:MIMOKanal}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{my.bib}

\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage[demo]{graphics}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
    @article{somebody-sgt,
      ids       =   {someone-sgt},
      author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
      title     =   {Some Great Title},
      journal   =   {Best Journal},
      year      =   3019,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      volume    =   3,
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[Test Test]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      Test Test, 1. Zeile \\
      Test Test, 2. Zeile \\
   \end{tabular}
   Quelle:~\cite[S. 23]{somebody-sgt}}
   }{\includegraphics{whatever}} \label{fig:MIMOKanal}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]